# Display Lists and OpenGL states

Tags: c++, opengl, frame-rate, displaylist

This is strange.

When I render my mesh, the fps is a stable 130 or so.

When I put it into a display list, the fps DROPS to little more than 15.

When I take out the few material and texturing commands, it goes back up to 130.

Why is this? Why are the OpenGL state changing commands so pressing on FPS? I think I read somewhere not to ever, ever do this.

Comment: OS?  OpenGL implementation vendor?

Comment: and also put what exactly you store into the display list.

Comment: Windows. I don't know. Nothing but the color/material commands and the code that renders the model (vertex arrays).

Comment: Are you sure you're not generating the list every frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common mistake is putting the display list creation into the render loop. Make sure you are creating the display list somewhere during initialization and only rendering it in the render loop. Aside from that, you will just have to post a code sample for us to look at.

Comment: No, it is only recreated when the mesh is changed.

Comment: And this problem is in the past. I'm not even using DLs anymore. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Good man. I didn't want to say it, but DLs are extremely primitive. There are far better ways to draw complex geometry. :)